# Literal does not match format string for Oracle SQL to_date on a string column

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, to-date

Dear SQL Gurus from Stack Overflow:

**Environment:** Oracle

I'm trying to understand why I can't do a to_date selection on a table column that contains strings. Note tableZ with a column of name Value in the example below contains a bunch of strings, some of which are the correct format, for example 6/20/2010 00:00:00.

tableZ

```
| Value              |
| __________________ |
| 6/21/2010 00:00:00 |
| Somestring         |
| Some Other strings |
| 6/21/2010 00:00:00 |
| 6/22/2010 00:00:00 |
```

**The following works**

```
SELECT To_Date(c.Value, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') somedate 
          FROM tableX a, tableY b, tableZ c 
         WHERE Lower(a.name) = 'somedate' 
           AND a.id = b.other_id 
           AND b.id = c.new_id
```

This returns something like (which is good):

```
| somedate            |
| __________________  |
| 21.06.2010 00:00:00 |
| 21.06.2010 00:00:00 |
| 22.06.2010 00:00:00 |
```

**The following does not work**

```
SELECT To_Date(c.Value, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') somedate 
          FROM properties$aud a, template_properties$aud b, consumable_properties$aud c 
         WHERE Lower(a.name) = 'somedate' 
           AND a.id = b.property_id 
           AND b.id = c.template_property_id 
           AND To_Date(c.Value, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') IS NOT NULL
```

Comes back with:

***ORA-01861: literal does not match format string***

What am I missing here? Just a quick note:

```
 ...
AND b.id = c.template_property_id 
AND To_Date(c.Value, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') IS NOT NULL
```

doesn't work either.

Thanks!!

**Goal** to be able to do date BETWEEN queries on c.value in order to select date ranges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The order that Oracle evaluates the conditions found in the where clause is not fixed.  That is to say that it can choose to evaluate the condition containing TO_DATE before the other criteria, in which case the query will fail.  To prevent that, add the ordered_predicates hint to your query, but be aware that this may require additional manual tuning to improve performance.

```
SELECT /*+ ordered_predicates */
               To_Date(c.Value, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') somedate 
          FROM properties$aud a, 
               template_properties$aud b, 
               consumable_properties$aud c 
         WHERE Lower(a.name) = 'somedate' 
           AND a.id = b.property_id 
           AND b.id = c.template_property_id 
           AND To_Date(c.Value, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') IS NOT NULL
```

---

Apparently `ordered_predicates` is deprecated starting with 10g.  In that case, I think your only option is to use a sub-query in such a way that optimizer is forced to evaluate it first (i.e. it can't combine the queries).  The easiest way to do this is to put `rownum` in the where statement of the inner query.

```
SELECT To_Date(c.Value, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') somedate 
  FROM (SELECT value 
          FROM properties$aud a, 
               template_properties$aud b, 
               consumable_properties$aud c 
         WHERE Lower(a.name) = 'somedate' 
           AND a.id = b.property_id 
           AND b.id = c.template_property_id
           AND rownum > 0) 
 WHERE To_Date(c.Value, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: A neat idea but I didn't get it to work with initial testing?

Comment: @Rio, if you want more help, saying "I didn't get it to work" is not good enough.

Comment: His comment was in response to just the ordered_predicate section.  The rest was added when I researched why it wasn't working...

Comment: Thank you Allan. This answer is valuable and hopefully will enlighten others as well!

Comment: As I understand it, the Oracle optimizer will sometimes push predicates into the in-line view, resulting in to_date and to_number firing on invalid values, even when the in-line view should filter them out. This is unfortunate, in cases like this example. See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:11504677087008 and http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/1351381.htm

Comment: @Shannon Severance, that is correct.  However, you can prevent oracle from pushing the predicate to the in-line view by adding a value to that view that would be changed if the predicate is changed.  That's the purpose of including rownum in the inner query.

Answer (score 4):

Another technique is embed the conversion in a CASE.
For example

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE col_a = '1'
AND case when col_a = '1' then to_date(col_b,'DD/MM/YYYY') end = trunc(sysdate)
```

This gets REALLY ugly fast when the clauses are complicated though.

Answer (score 2):

```
create or replace function to_date_or_null(v_str_date in varchar2
        , v_str_fmt in varchar2 default null) return date as
begin
    if v_str_fmt is null then
        return to_date(v_str_date);
    else
        return to_date(v_str_date, v_str_fmt);
    end if;
exception
    when others then
        return null;
end to_date_or_null;
/
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select to_date_or_null('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual -- Valid;

TO_DATE_OR_NULL('20
-------------------
2000-01-01 00:00:00

SQL> select to_date_or_null('Not a date at all') from dual -- Not Valid;

TO_DATE_OR_NULL('NO
-------------------


SQL> select to_date_or_null('2000-01-01') from dual -- Valid matches my NLS settings;

TO_DATE_OR_NULL('20
-------------------
2000-01-01 00:00:00

SQL> select to_date_or_null('01-Jan-00') from dual -- Does not match my NLS settings;

TO_DATE_OR_NULL('01
-------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check if c.value is a valid format with

```
AND To_Date(c.Value, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') IS NOT NULL
```

? This wont work, you will need to perform the check in some other way. You could use a regular expression (i guess, not used them in a while). Better yet if your data model would allow you to discern the rows in question.

Comment: No, my goal as stated above is to do BETWEEN queries so that I can select date ranges. The IS NOT NULL is just a simple way for me to check if the query works at all, and the oracle error suggests otherwise.